# How to redirect on click Notification?

Tags: javascript, laravel, notifications, pusher

I implemented a notification on pusher call, but when I call pusher notification is displayed but not getting redirected to the URL?

My Pusher Code :

```
 <script src="https://js.pusher.com/7.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        var pusher = new Pusher('85066e9308022d00ffa2', {
            cluster: 'mt1'
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('request');
        channel.bind('VehicleRequest', function (data) {

            location.reload();

            shownotification();
        });
    </script>
```

My notification Code :

```
<script>

        function shownotification() {
            const notification = new Notification("New Request!", {
                body: "Please Check New Request",

            });
            notification.onclick = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = '{{ url("") }}';
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to open a new webpage when a user clicks on the notification, is that correct?

Comment: yes, I need to open new webpage @doydoy

Answer (score 0):

Change `window.location.href = '{{ url("") }};` to `window.open(url,'_blank');`